# Discretising Hexgonal Brillouin Zone

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals, electronic-band-theory

I am looking at a system at which I have a 2D Hexagonal Brillouin Zone (BZ). The aim is to take the following type of procedure:
$$
\frac{A}{(2\pi)^2}\int_{BZ} F(\vec{k}) d\vec{k} \hspace{5pt} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{N}\sum_{BZ}F(\vec{k})
$$
which is taking the integration to a summation over the BZ. Therefore, I want to discretise the hexagon into points of $\vec{k}=(k_x,k_y)$ which are contained inside the BZ itself.
I have looked at the Monkhorst-Pack grid which generates the k-points with respect to the reciprocal lattice vectors $\vec{b}_1,\vec{b}_2$. However, if you were to view all the k-points this generates it would generate a 'parallelogram' nature similar to the image below in which all the hexagonal BZ is not covered by the discretised k-points.

[image: Hexagonal k-point grid from Ref1]

My question then leads to how can one efficiently obtain all the k-points inside an hexagonal BZ such that all the features are obtained, including at all the edges of the BZ

Ref [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtRXl.png) - Kratzer, Peter & Neugebauer, Jörg. (2019). The Basics of Electronic Structure Theory for Periodic Systems. Frontiers in Chemistry. 7. 106. 10.3389/fchem.2019.00106.